# How to search for bold paragraphs either in selected text or from a certain point in a document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code that deletes the paragraph following any entirely bold paragraphs in the whole document. How can I amend it so that it affects only some of the text, specifically, from a certain point where the cursor is to the end of the document? Thanks

```
Dim para As Paragraph

For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If para.Range.Font.Bold = True Then para.Next.Range.Delete
Next para
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict the search range you need to replace `ActiveDocument` with the range you want to search. Whenever you write code in Word it is best to avoid using the `Selection` object. Using `Selection` moves the cursor around on the screen which means the screen must be redrawn each time. This is avoided by using the `Range` object instead.

```
  Dim para As Paragraph
  Dim searchRange As Range

  'pick up the start of the range
  Set searchRange = Selection.Range
  'move the end of the range to the end of the document
  searchRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End
  For Each para In searchRange.Paragraphs
    If para.Range.Font.Bold = True Then para.Next.Range.Delete
  Next para
```